# Run command before all tests

Tags: phpunit, symfony

I have created a Symfony Command to reset my Application to an initial state. To run that command from the cli I need to type:

```
php bin/console app:reset
```

I would like to run that command **once before all** unit tests. I could manage to do that **before each test** and surely before **all classes**. Therefore I used that code:

```
public function setUp()
{
    $kernel = new \AppKernel('test', true);
    $kernel->boot();
    $app = new \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application($kernel);
    $app->setAutoExit(false);

    $app->run(new ArrayInput([
        'command' => 'app:reset', ['-q']
    ]), new NullOutput());
}
```

As mentioned above, that is working nice before each test and with `setUpBeforeClass()` I could have that before each class, but once before all tests would be sufficient, since that command take some time to run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Symfony docs explain how to do this: [How to Customize the Bootstrap Process before Running Tests](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/bootstrap.html)

In short, you need to modify the `phpunit.xml.dist` to call your own bootstrap instead of the default one (and delegate to the default bootstrap).

Comment: That was the easiest way to do that.

Comment: With your explanation there is no need to go to Symfony docs. Thanks. It  is working as charm.

Answer (score 7):

You could implement [a test listener](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/extending-phpunit.html#extending-phpunit.examples.SimpleTestListener.php) and use a static property to make sure your command is executed only once.

Example for PHPUnit 5.4:

```php
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class AppResetTestListener extends PHPUnit_Framework_BaseTestListener
{
    static $wasCalled = false;

    public function startTestSuite(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite $suite)
    {
        if (!self::$wasCalled) {
            // @todo call your command

            self::$wasCalled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need to [enable the test listener](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.test-listeners) in your `phpunit.xml` config.

Read more:

- [Extending PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/extending-phpunit.html)
- [Test listeners](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.test-listeners)

Comment: Good Idea, gonna check it out!

Comment: After some experimentation I found out you can also use a regular member variable. This way you can make a base class that multiple "run-once" child listeners can inherit from. Similarly, each listener can register itself as a shutdown function (do this from the base class) to provide an `endTestSuite` functionality.